# remove dollar match regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Ive been using this regex expression to validate a dollar amount input.

```
parsley-regexp="^\$?[0-9][0-9\,]*(\.\d{1,2})?$|^\$?[\.]([\d][\d]?)$"
```

I no longer want to allow the $ sign, just the valid amount. What changes do I need to make?

Comment: Your regular expressions matches `$1,,,,2,3.44` I suggest you look up some basics instead of using blindly copied code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove $ validation from your expression, use this:

```
parsley-regexp="[0-9][0-9\,]*(\.\d{1,2})?$|[\.]([\d][\d]?)$"
```

But, you may want to fix your expression to take only valid currency input. For example:

```
parsley-regexp="^\$?((\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(\.\d{1,2})?$";
```

Positive results: $1,234,456.00  |  $1.5   |  $1,00

Negative results: $1,23  |  $1,,,.24

This is how it works

```
^\$?                 - begins with one $ symbol
((\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*) - has 1-3 digits, followed by 1 or more occurrences of 'comma and 3 digits'
|(\d+))              - Or look for 1 or more digits
(\.\d{1,2})?         - one or more occurrences of . followed by 1-2 digits
```

To get rid of $ sign, just remove `^\$?`:

```
parsley-regexp="((\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(\.\d{1,2})?$";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for. Due to time constraints, this helps me a lot. Your thoughtful answer really encourages me to learn this when I have more time....

Answer (score 5):

Simple remove `\$?` (an optional escaped dollar sign - you needed to escape it as `$` is a reserved regex character):

```
// These are regex characters - keep them    v                    v
parsley-regexp="^\$?[0-9][0-9\,]*(\.\d{1,2})?$|^\$?[\.]([\d][\d]?)$"
// Remove these  ^^^                            ^^^
```

Comment: I guess the `?` after `\$` should be removed as well

Comment: @donfuxx Of course - you're completely right that `/^?` makes no sense.